# How to pass a variable from a parent HTML page into a child Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

So, I have a HTML page with an Iframe inside. Let's say that the HTML page has one field called "name" which value is whatever the user enters. What I need is a way to pass the value of "name" into a variable in the Iframe, without submitting the form. If there was also a way to pass the value of "name" into a hidden field on the Iframe, this would work as well.

The Iframe currently loads at the same time as the parent HTML page. I am aware that there are tons of questions on SO about passing values from an Iframe to the parent, but in this case I need to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selector', window.parent.document).html();
```

Will not work cross domain